# Show that f(z) = |z| is continuous (epsilon-delta)

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Use $||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|$ in the $\epsilon-\delta$ analysis.

It's been awhile since I've studied any kind of analysis, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. I want to show what I've done and see if it makes sense so far.

I need to show that for any $\epsilon$, I can find a $\delta$ such that $|a-b| < \delta \implies ||a|-|b|| < \epsilon$.

Using the hint, I break the problem into three cases:

Case (i) when $||a|-|b|| = |a-b|$, case (ii) when $||a|-|b|| < |a-b| < \epsilon$, case (iii) when $||a|-|b|| < \epsilon < |a-b|$.

For case (i), I let $\delta = \epsilon$. Then $|a-b| < \delta \implies ||a|-|b|| < \epsilon$.

For case (ii), I let $\delta = \frac{|a-b|+\epsilon}{2}$. Then $|a-b| < \delta \implies ||a|-|b|| < \epsilon$ (since $||a|-|b|| < |a-b| < \delta < \epsilon$) in this case.

I am not sure about the rest. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Why cases? $\delta=\epsilon$ works in general. If $c$ is a point and $|z-c|<\delta$ then $||z|-|c||\leq |z-c|<\delta=\epsilon$, using the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: Wait... I don't know why I used cases. So I can just say $\delta = \epsilon$, so $|a-b| < \delta \implies ||a|-|b|| < \epsilon$, and done?

Comment: yes, using the so-called reverse triangle inequality. Maybe you should also prove this fact in the hint.

Comment: remember that the idea here is that for any $\epsilon$ we need some $\delta$. You can chose the $\delta$ in this case. You could even do $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ or $\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$. Any $\delta \leq \epsilon$ works in this example (not in every example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for cases. Let $\epsilon >0$ and $\delta =\epsilon$. Then if $c\in \mathbb{C}$ and $|z-c|<\delta$, by the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality), 
$$||z|-|c||\leq |z-c|<\delta=\epsilon,$$
hence the function $f(z)=|z|$ is continuous at $c$. The link contains a proof of the fact used here, by the way.